# Why PostgreSQL installer freeze on nw.dll?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a problem during the installation of **PostgreSQL 16.1** (official installer from [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)).
The installer runs fine until it trys to install **pgadmin** and then freeze on copying/unpacking **nw.dll**.

[image]

When I look in the install dir the file it there.

[image]

I tried several times as user or as admin, but the result is the same. Of course I deleted all reg keys and dirs before new try. The Postgres service obviously doesn't start/run since this installation step is never reached.

**Antivirus**: only Windows Defender, no thirt party apps.

**My System:**

- Windows 10 Enterprise x64 (22H2 build:19045)
- i7-4800MQ
- 32,0 GB RAM

Does anyone had the same issue? Any idea what's case this behaviour?

Comment: It's worth checking the installer logs, although it's clearly not finishing the unpacking process. You might want to check the window defender logs too - see if it is preventing this. Failing that, confirm the checksums on your download - maybe the package itself downloaded badly?

Comment: I'm wondering what the red font means in Explorer. I've never seen it myself, but I can't find anything in Google.

Comment: Hello @RichardHuxton! In Windows Defender log hasn't any records for this issue - nothing blocking. Unfortunately, there is no checksum on website I can compare to. Installer log doesn't contain any errors, but the last records show, that it unpacks python packages. `Unpacking C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery_cache\documents\vision.v1.json
Unpacking C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\python\Lib\site-`. As you can see it stoped logging in the middle of the line.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm using TotalCommander as file explorer. It has nothing to do with the error.